Using Auth.js for app and api on different ports
I have a ReactJS app running on port 5000 and a nextjs api running on port 4001. I am trying to use NextAuth V5 with the ResendAdapter for emails. Everything works fine until the backend API tries to redirect a page on the client and I begin to get CORS errors.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4001/auth/verify' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4001/api/auth/signin/resend') from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I do not know what the issue is. Is this possible to even use NextAuth when the api and web projects exist on different ports in a monorepo? thanks.

In your Next Auth configuration (backend), add these settings


export const authOptions = {
  callbacks: {
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      if (url.startsWith("/")) return `${baseUrl}${url}`
      else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url
      return baseUrl
    }
  }
}



And in your next.js API configuration, add CORS middleware


module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        headers: [
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', value: 'true' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: 'http://localhost:5000' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', value: 'GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', value: 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version' },
        ],
      },
    ]
  }
}



And you will need to make sure to include credentials in your fetch requests.
enter code here

